# Accessibility Regarding href="#"

Tags: navigation, accessibility, wcag

I'm building out a site (in WordPress, for context) that needs to be WCAG compliant. I have a main navigation built out to be fully keyboard-navigable, including toggling submenus.

The issue that I'm running into is: of my navigation items that contain a submenu, some actually link to a page, while others use href="#", as they contain a submenu but don't actually link anywhere.

Ordinarily I'd use an aria-label on the navigation items that use href="#", but since they're auto-generated (by WordPress) I can't do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is this even a relevant WCAG issue? Each of the href="#" navigation items are followed by a chevron (to toggle their submenu) which contains an arial-label of "Toggle submenu". Is that good enough?

Thanks!

**Edit:** The particular task for which I was trying to get this question answered has been put on hold. Once it's resolved I can update this question with the solution we pursued. I'm marking @slugolicious's answer as preferred because in his comments he provides a logical explanation as to why keeping the current system of inconsistent top-level navigation items is inadvisable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to wordpress but can comment on the html that *should* be generated, but some of what is generated depends on the behavior you want.

Do you want the user to open the menu and arrow up/down through the list or do you want them to <kbd>tab</kbd> through the list?

The former requires you to manage the focus yourself (keyboard handler for the arrow keys and maintaining the `tabindex` attribute) whereas the latter is much simpler - the browser can handle tabbing through the links in the menu.

Usually, if your menu is for navigation, then the latter is desired.

For the former (arrow key navigation), the menu roles ([menu](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#menu), [menuitem](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#menuitem)) and attributes ([aria-haspopup](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-haspopup)) should be used.  When a screen reader sees those properties, it tells the user to use the arrow keys to navigate.  If you have a menuitem that has a submenu, then that menuitem should have aria-haspopup specified.

For the latter (<kbd>tab</kbd> key navigation), do not use any of the aforementioned menu roles.  Rather, your menu should just be a list (`<ul>`) of links (with the list normally having `list-style:none`).  If any of your list items have a submenu, they should contain a sublist (nested `<ul>`) and the list item should have the [aria-expanded](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded) attribute.

Regarding the chevron for the submenus, is the chevron a separate tab stop?

**Update** to answer additional question asked by @LCW in the first comment of this answer.

`aria-expanded` goes on the element that you select to display the submenu, so in your case, it would be the chevron itself, at least from what I understand about your description.  It sounds like if you select a link, it goes to another page, but if you select the chevron, it opens a submenu under that item?  If so, then your code would be something like this:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>menu item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>menu item 2</a>
      <button aria-expanded="false">chevron</button>
      <ul style="display: none">
        <li>
          <a>submenu item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>submenu item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>menu item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The chevron button has `aria-expanded="false"` initially and when you selected it, you should toggle the value to "true" and unhide the submenu.  You can see a similar example of this on the Abercrombie & Fitch shopping page, https://www.abercrombie.com/shop/us.  However, A&F hide the chevron until you <kbd>TAB</kbd> to it.  Mouse users will never see it because the submenu opens on mouse hover.  They have `aria-expanded` set on their chevron too.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'm using the tab-key navigation. The entire navigation can already be operated using the tab-key. The chevrons for the submenus are separate tab stops with tabindex="0". Could you clarify which elements require the aria-expanded attribute in a navigation comprised of nested <ul>s, as you described above for the tab-key navigation?

Comment: You wrote "It sounds like if you select a link, it goes to another page, but if you select the chevron, it opens a submenu under that item?" That's entirely correct, and the Abercrombie navigation is a good example, but there's one exception: some of my links don't go anywhere. They have no href, just a chevron. We simply didn't have pages for them to link to, so they act more like "descriptions" of their submenus. Do these "links" that don't link anywhere need an aria-label?

Comment: That might be a design/usability issue because now you have items that are not consistent. Links without a chevron take you to another page. That's fine and consistent. Links with a chevron **might** take you to another page. That feels weird. The only reason to have a chevron is because the link itself goes to another page but you also want to display a submenu under that link. But you also have links that don't go to another page but still have a submenu. I think that needs to be discussed with your designer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not a WCAG violation to have empty links. However, if the primary purpose of having the link is only to trigger a JS function then it's problematic for Screen reader users. 
There wouldn't be any difference when SR reads

```
    <a href="#">HTML</a> vs <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">HTML</a>.
```

Both would be read as "Link HTML" and so users would expect the link to open in a new tab and navigate away from the current page and display related information.

If you can't use aria-label/aria-labelledby/aria-describedby to clarify the link purpose 
to the user, then I would suggest using (button) tag instead of anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `<a>`s don't trigger JS. Some of the `<a>`s link to separate pages, as expected from a normal navigation item. Others contain submenus, but don't actually link anywhere. They act as a kind of "parent link" that categorizes the submenu links it contains. The submenus are toggled via interacting with a chevron (this interaction requires JS but I have control over the chevron aria-label so they're not an issue).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the core question here is ... how do I modify the default HTML elements that a Wordpress menu spits out.

Then you can apply whatever Accessibility features you want.

https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/

This is dated but should point you in the right direction. There are LOTS of different ways your theme could be out putting navigation. If that guide does not cover how your theme is generating navigation, more information about your wordpress/theme setup is necessary to analyze further.